# Set div elememt same height as parent

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/0zqd2pa6/

I'm trying to make the blocks inside the row the same height as it's containing row.

I can alert the height but doesn't change the height of the div's

```
$('.block').height($(this).parent().parent().height());
//alert($('.block').parent().parent().height())
```

Comment: The solution is in the answer below, but next time I recommend you to use Foundation with the Equalizer function. It works really fine. Forget bootstrap and go to future with Foundation. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html

Comment: $(this) is refer to windows. windows does not have parents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet fixing your issue, using `height()` function parameter and `closest()` method to target specific `.row`:

```
$('.block').height(function(){
    return $(this).closest('.row').height();
});
```

### -jsFiddle-